# Setup VNC on headless Raspberry Pi using Ubuntu 23.04 can't open display

Tags: server, raspberrypi, vnc, 23.04

Attempting to setup TigerVNC on Ubuntu 23.04 using Raspberry Pi 4B.
Got to step to test by entering 'vncserver'.
Received this output:

```
New Xtigervnc server 'KG7JE-Ham:1 (steve)' on port 5901 for display :1.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.IZRuvV/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
```

--- `tail /home/steve/.vnc/KG7JE-Ham:1.log` ---

```
Session startup via '/home/steve/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 576114... success!
```

So, tried `tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm` with this output:

```
New Xtigervnc server 'KG7JE-Ham:1 (steve)' on port 5901 for display :1.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.aBtKL_/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
```

That appears to work as I see the lock file in `/tmp/`.
So, what is going wrong with vncserver?

Here is output of `./.vnc/*.log`:

```
_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.12.0 - built 2023-01-06 16:01
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12101006, X.Org


Thu Jul  6 13:38:17 2023
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
3NI3X0 New Xtigervnc server 'KG7JE-Ham:1 (steve)' on port 5901 for display :1.
3NI3X0 Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.OPtlxa/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1

Thu Jul  6 13:38:18 2023
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:nan ratio)
xrdb: Connection reset by peer
xrdb: Can't open display ':1'
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

Comment: Based on feedback from Ham forums, decided to use Rasperian on the Pi instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line:

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
```

What worked for me was to remove the "&"  in the following line of my xstartup:

```
startxfce4 &
```

So, my line now is simply:

```
startxfce4
```

I found this solution here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1411871#p1411871

Hope it helps.